# Powershell - Identify if WIN Product key is Pro or Home or whatewer

Tags: windows, powershell, key, licensing

I need to change key on several computers from KMS to OEM.
I'm able to get the OEM key using -   `Get-WmiObject -Class SoftwareLicensingService`

Yet I would like to test, if the key is actually
**WIN 10 Pro key** , not home, pro for workstation etc.

Any idea how to check it, ideally with Powershell ?
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if that helps, but you could get system data `systeminfo /FO CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv` - but be aware that you might get problems with other OS languages

Comment: Why not look at the OS Name? `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).Name.Split("|")[0]`.

Comment: You may have better luck searching through the (string array) output of [slmgr.vbs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/activation-slmgr-vbs-options): `cscript.exe //nologo C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs /dli` or `cscript.exe //nologo C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs /dlv` (for extended info)

Comment: Hi,  thanks everyone for ideas, It turns out I just did not notice - `get-wmiObject -query "select * from SoftwareLicensingService" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty OA3xOriginalProductKeyDescription`